# Finding data on XML using Python's LXML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Using Python's LXML I must read an XML file and print from each "basic" and "expert" tag, the name and email text from it. I've done a script that works but I don't think is the best way of doing this. Is there a better (simpler) way for getting the data of the XML without having to make 2 iterations on it?

Python so far:

```
from lxml import etree

myXML = "data.xml"
tree = etree.parse(myXML)
root = tree.getroot()
for node in root:
    if node.tag == "basic" or node.tag == "expert":
        user = [None] * 4
        for i, child in enumerate(node):
            if child.tag == "name":
                user[0] = i
                user[1] = child.text
            if child.tag == "email":
                user[2] = i
                user[3] = child.text
        print user
        if user[3].startswith('_'):
            # do some other things with data if email begins with _ ...
```

Will print:

```
[0, 'f.bar', 1, 'foobar@me.com']
[0, 'm.bob', 3, 'm.bob@email.com']
[0, 'm.bab', 3, 'm.bab@email.com']
```

XML sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
    <id>11111</id>
    <checked>True</checked>
    <version>A12</mode>
    <basic>
        <name>f.bar</name>
        <email>foobar@me.com</email>
        <forename>Foo</forename>
        <surname>Bar</surname>
    </basic>
    <expert>
        <name>m.bob</name>
        <forename>Mak</forename>
        <surname>Bob</surname>
        <email>m.bob@email.com</password>
    </expert>
    <expert>
        <name>m.bab</name>
        <forename>Mak</forename>
        <surname>Bab</surname>
        <email>m.bab@email.com</password>
    </expert>
    <guru>
        <name>e.guru</name>
        <forename>Nick</forename>
        <email>nick@email.com</password>
        <surname>Gru</surname>
    </guru>
</users>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you are overlooking one of the advantages in using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text) with its fully compilant W3C [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) (even XSLT 1.0) language modules.

Right now, your code really follows the syntax of Python's built-in `etree`, without any `xpath()` calls that can run dynamic parsing off node names.

Below iterates through all `<basic>` and `<expert>` tags and retrieves their child `<name>` and `<email>` all in one loop or list comprehension. And to retrieve their position we count their preceding siblings with `count(preceding-sibling::*)`.

```
from lxml import etree

myXML = "data.xml"
tree = etree.parse(myXML)

user = []

# FOR LOOP
for i in tree.xpath("//*[name()='basic' or name()='expert']"):
    user.append([i.xpath("count(name/preceding-sibling::*)"), 
                 i.find("name").text, 
                 i.xpath("count(email/preceding-sibling::*)"), 
                 i.find("email").text])        
print(user)
# [[0.0, 'f.bar', 1.0, 'foobar@me.com'], 
#  [0.0, 'm.bob', 3.0, 'm.bob@email.com'], 
#  [0.0, 'm.bab', 3.0, 'm.bab@email.com']]


# LIST COMPREHENSION
user = [[i.xpath("count(name/preceding-sibling::*)"), 
         i.find("name").text, 
         i.xpath("count(email/preceding-sibling::*)"), 
         i.find("email").text] 
        for i in tree.xpath("//*[name()='basic' or name()='expert']")]

print(user)
# [[0.0, 'f.bar', 1.0, 'foobar@me.com'], 
#  [0.0, 'm.bob', 3.0, 'm.bob@email.com'], 
#  [0.0, 'm.bab', 3.0, 'm.bab@email.com']]
```

Comment: But how to get also the position of the searched child? Look at original code.. user[0] = i and user[2] = i. As XML format is not the same for basic and expert, I need this information.

Comment: Understood. See edit still using an XPath solution with `count(.../preceding-sibling::*)`.